# How to return values when observer.complete() is called

Tags: angular, rxjs, publish-subscribe, observer-pattern

```
 if (md5hash === payload.md5hash) {
            result = {
              path: payload.localFilePath,
              length: payload.length,
              md5hash: payload.md5hash
            };
            // HOW TO RETURN result before observer complete is called ???
            observer.complete();
```

Please help me , I am new to Angular

Comment: Please _do not_ post screenshots of code. It makes it incredibly hard to reproduce the issue. Also you need to provide more code. What exactly are you doing before the `observer.complete()`?

Comment: I have pasted, please have a look into that

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
let obs = Observable.create(observer => { 
    if (md5hash === payload.md5hash) {
        observer.next( {
              path: payload.localFilePath,
              length: payload.length,
              md5hash: payload.md5hash
            });
        observer.complete();
    }
    else {
        observer.error('error');
    }
});

obs.subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
})
```